# What's the mobile industry standard for handling timezones?

Tags: ios, .net, timezone, standards, web-standards

I make mobile apps that use web services coming from a .NET server that I do not control.

We always run into trouble when scheduling events that are in different timezones.

The server is on EST time and much of the data coming from the web services are presented this way.

We end up having to add display dates fields and it's very confusing.

In addition, I have code that is essentially the same except it depends if I'm talking to the server or if I'm calculating something on the device. Also a pain.

Here is an example of what I'm doing to handle the EST times:

#### Data Coming In:

```
- (void)initWithWebServiceData:(NSDictionary *)data {

    self.scheduleDate = [self dateFromDotNetJSONString:data[@"ScheduleDate"]];

    //...and other stuff
}

- (NSDate *)dateFromDotNetJSONString:(NSString *)stringInEST {

    int secondsESToffset = 14400;

    static NSRegularExpression *dateRegEx = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        dateRegEx = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"^\\/date\\((-?\\d++)(?:([+-])(\\d{2})(\\d{2}))?\\)\\/$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    });
    NSTextCheckingResult *regexResult = [dateRegEx firstMatchInString:stringInEST options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringInEST length])];

    if (regexResult) {
        // milliseconds
        NSTimeInterval seconds = [[stringInEST substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:1]] doubleValue] / 1000.0;
        // timezone offset
        if ([regexResult rangeAtIndex:2].location != NSNotFound) {
            NSString *sign = [stringInEST substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:2]];
            // hours
            seconds += [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", sign, [stringInEST substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:3]]] doubleValue] * 60.0 * 60.0;
            // minutes
            seconds += [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", sign, [stringInEST substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:4]]] doubleValue] * 60.0;
        }
        return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds - secondsESToffset];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

#### Data Going Out:

```
- (void)requestRegistrationForEvent
{        
    NSString *fullDateTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [self.scheduleDate webServiceStringValue], [self.scheduleDate dateTimeText]];

    [self.dataController requestRegistrationForEvent:[self.eventID stringValue]
                                              onDate:fullDateTime];
}

- (NSString *)webServiceStringValue {

    NSString *webServiceStringValue = nil;

    if ([self isKindOfClass:NSDate.class]) {
        NSDate *date = (NSDate *)self;

        //format the date how the web service expects it
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"M/d/yyyy"];

        NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];

        webServiceStringValue = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    }
    return webServiceStringValue;
}

- (NSString *)dateTimeText {

    NSString *text = @"";
    NSDate *date;

    if ([self isKindOfClass:NSDate.class]) {

        date = (NSDate *)self;

        NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];

        NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
        [timeFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];

        text = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:date];

        text = [text lowercaseString];
        text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    }
    return text;
}
```

### Question

Am I doing something wrong and what can I recommend to my .NET partner to handle timezones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so much about a mobile industry standard as an integration and international time standard: timestamps should use always use offsets or UTC (zulu) time. GMT is a timezone, like EST, so UTC is preferred as a universal time. It just so happens that GMT does not observe daylight savings time so it is often interchangeable. Your partner should send timestamps in the UTC standard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601, which looks like `2014-11-09T10:37:27+00:00`, or zulu: `2014-11-09T10:37:27Z`. Sometimes folks use variants such as `2014-11-09 10:37:27UTC`, but you can build a date formatter for any of them.

The date format will be `dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz"`. I usually put a UTC date format factory into an NSDateFormatter category.

If the day is the only thing that matters and the exact time truly doesn't, than your method should be sufficient, except that you will also need to format anything resulting from the timestamp without times or do calculations using calendars.